# Java: Create temporary path in Amazon S3 to create files inside

Tags: java, amazon-s3, playframework

I need to create a temporary folder in Amazon S3 to create files, work on them and then delete them.

How do I create this temporary folder and read it to create the file?

```
File file = new File(<<TEMPORARY PATH AMAZON>> + reportName);
```

Answer (score 4):

S3 files are not available to the JVM as files, so you cannot use the normal Java File class.

Instead, you use the AWS Java [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-java/). More specifically, you will use [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html).

The S3 model is pretty simple. You can create a limited number of "buckets." In your case, you probably want to just create one bucket for use for storing temporary files, although the SDK does allow you to create and delete buckets whenever you want. Bucket names have to be globally unique.

Within a bucket, you can create as many objects (files) as you want. By convention, fakey folders are implemented by using "/" characters in the "key" (name) of the file. This convention is supported by some functions that allow you to operate on all files that have a certain prefix in their keys. In addition, the S3 Console presents these as folders.

Versioning can be turned on for your bucket, in which case all versions of all files are maintained.

The SDK supports API calls for reading and writing files as well as accessing ancillary data such as create time, etc.